# Using PowerShell to update items declared as records

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

Wanted to check if anyone knew of a more efficient way of updating documents.

Using a CAML query to return documents from a library. The returned documents need be undeclared as a record, checked out, updated, checked in, then declared as a record.

In the below script, you will notice that I'm having to execute several .GetItems calls.  Without the calls, an error is returned after each action stating the item has been modified by Admin account.

```
$spQuery.Query = $caml 

do
{
 $listItems = $list.GetItems($spQuery)
 $spQuery.ListItemCollectionPosition = $listItems.ListItemCollectionPosition
 foreach($item in $listItems)
{
  $itemID = $item.id
  $recordsmanagement::UndeclareItemAsRecord($item)
  $item = $list.GetItemById($itemID) 
  $item.File.CheckOut()

  $item["Some Field"]=$nSomeUpdate

  $item.Update() 
  $item = $list.GetItemById($item.id) 
  $item.File.CheckIn("Content Update")
  $item = $list.GetItemById($item.id)
  $recordsmanagement::DeclareItemAsRecord($item)
}

}
while ($spQuery.ListItemCollectionPosition -ne $null)
```

Comment: Strange to update a record! Make a copy and declare a new record. That way you retain your chain of proof.

Comment: The metadata on the item needs to be updated to ensure relevance.